# JS: Using variable names to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, variables

Im working with jQuery. I have an app that makes ajax requests to server that responds with JSON.

in some cases the response from the server will indicate the name of a JS function to be called

```
{"responseType":"callback", "callback":"STUFF.TestCallback","callbackData":"this is in the callback"}
```

If the responseType is "callback" as above the JSON is passed to a function to handle this response type. (the var "response" contains the JSON above)

```
STUFF.callback = function(response){
    if(typeof response.callback =='function'){
        console.log("All Good")
        response.callback(response);
    }else{
        console.log("Hmm... Cant find function",response.callback );
    }
}


STUFF.TestCallBack = function(data){
    alert("it worked"); 
}
```

But when I do this I get the error "response.callback is not a function".

Any comments on why this is not working and how to do this properly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A String is a String, not a Function.

`response.callback()` doesn't work because it is the same as `"STUFF.TestCallback"()` not `STUFF.TestCallback()`

You probably want to have the data structured something more like `"callback": "TestCallback"` then then do:

```
STUFF[response.callback](response);
```

Here you use the String to access a property of `STUFF`. (`foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` being equivalent.)

Comment: Thanks David! Makes perfect sense in hind sight!

Answer (score 1):

You could transform that "namespace.func" into a call like this:

```
STUFF.callback = function(response) {
  var fn = response.callback.split("."), func = window;
  while(func && fn.length) { func = func[fn.shift()]; }
  if(typeof func == 'function') {
    console.log("All Good")
    func(response);
  } else{
    console.log("Hmm... Cant find function", response.callback);
  }
}
```

What this does it grab the function by getting `window["STUFF"]` then `window["STUFF"]["TestCallback"]` as it loops, checking if each level is defined as it goes to prevent error.  Note that this works for any level function as well, for example `"STUFF.One.Two.func"` will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You propably could do

```
var myfunction = eval(response.callback);
myfunction(response);
```

although using eval() is considered as a bad style by some javascript developers.

Comment: Bad style. Hard to maintain. Hard to debug. Slow and inefficient. Good source of security problems.